# MKMapView (annotations & locations) - iPhone development

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

How can I determine the coordinates of a certain spot?
How can I create a pin for 1 specific location after knowing it's coordinates? Is creating a new class for that necessary?

ex- PIN to :    latitude = 37.786996;
                longitude = -122.440100;

Comment: Define "a certain spot"?

Comment: check out this link dude http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Listings/main_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746-main_m-DontLinkElementID_14

Answer (score 2):

To add a *basic* pin at a given coordinate, the simplest way in iOS 4+ is to use the pre-defined `MKPointAnnotation` class (no need to define your own class) and call `addAnnotation:`.

If you need to define your own annotation class because you need some custom properties, don't use the classes shown in the `MapCallouts` sample app as a basis.  They give the false impression that you need to define a separate class for each unique coordinate.  Instead, create a class that implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol but with a settable `coordinate` property.

**Edit:**
An example with `MKPointAnnotation`:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(33, 35);
annotation.title = @"Title";
annotation.subtitle = @"Subtitle";
[mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
[annotation release];
```

If you need to easily access the annotation in other methods in the class, you can make it an ivar instead.

Comment: how can i create a MKPointAnnotation of coordinates  33 , 35  to be able to use the addAnnotation later on?

Comment: How to add multiple pins in an MKMapView?

Comment: @PradeepReddyKypa, You should ask a new question with info on where your multiple pin data is (plist, sql, array, dictionary, other) and what you've tried.  Basically, call addAnnotation repeatedly for each annotation (eg. in a loop).  Searching on SO should give you numerous examples.

Comment: @AnnaKarenina : Thanks for the response. I have asked my question at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730400/how-to-display-and-connect-multiple-locations-with-a-route-with-annotations-in-a" . My data is hardcoded. I cant repeat that inside a loop as the location details(lat and long) are different.

Answer (score 0):

You implement an object that supports the MKMapAnnotation protocol. This object you add to your mkmapview with the "addAnnotation:" call. This will give you the default pin on the map.

If you want to customize the pin you need to implement the MKMapViewDelegate protocol to return an MKAnnotationView with a custom image.